# Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Id at line 14 column 9

Tags: apex

Good day I am getting the error show below:

> Compile Error: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Id at line 14 column 9

I am trying to write a test class for my controller which basically updates data in  an existing Lead record.

**Controller Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
Public class TestCIFController {
Static TestMethod void TestCIFController ()
{  
    Lead lead = new Lead(id='00Q2C000001Iwku');
    PageReference pageRef = Page.CIF;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);   
   // Lead leadid = new Lead('00Q2C000001Iwku');
    Test.startTest();

    List<Lead> leadData=[SELECT lastname, Date_Of_Registration__c, Customer_Name__c, Business_Profile__c, Surname_and_First_Name__c, Job_Title__c, Telephone_Number__c, Email__c, Trading_As__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: lead.id];

        System.assertEquals(1, leadData.size());
    update lead.id;

    Attachment identityDoc= new Attachment();     
        identityDoc.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob idBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        identityDoc.body = idBlob;
        identityDoc.parentId=lead.id;
        insert identityDoc;

    List<Attachment> IdAttachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:lead.id];
        System.assertEquals(2, IdAttachments.size()); 


    Attachment bizDoc= new Attachment();     
        bizDoc.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob bizBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        bizDoc.body=bizBlob;
        bizDoc.parentId=lead.id;
        insert bizDoc;

    List<Attachment> BIZattachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:lead.id];
        System.assertEquals(3, BizAttachments.size());


    Test.stopTest(); 

    System.debug('****'+lead.id);
}
}
```

Please kindly assist. Many thanks

Comment: DML Statement like Insert,Update works only for sObject/sObject list as the error describes. So change this line `update lead.id;` to `update lead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have:

```
update lead.id;
```

You should instead have:

```
update lead;
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Aidan m waiting for the time to mark your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At line 14 you are trying to perform DML on lead id. It should be on lead record as follows -

```
update lead;
```

But as you want to test if its getting updated through controller, you shouldn't be doing this in test class. Call the controller from test class and check in an assert if it is updated.